# Rails 3.2: use eager loaded relations in after_initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relation

I want to do some operations on a relation if it has been eager laded (e.g. via `includes`). In concret terms, I have a data structure `Thread` which contains n `Message`s. I want to create a tree of the messages when they're eager loaded. I tried it as follows:

```
class Thread
  has_many :messages

  after_initialize do
    gen_tree if messages.loaded?
  end
end
```

My Problem is that the hook is executed before the the relations have been loaded. Same with `after_find`.

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Greetings,
 CK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I found is renaming the existing relation method and implement your own:

```
class Thread
  has_many :messages

  alias_method :messages_orig, :messages
  def messages
    ret = messages_orig

    unless @generated
      @generated = true
      gen_tree
      sort_tree
    end

    ret
  end
end
```

As far as I tested it, it has no negative side effects.

LG,
 CK